# How do I kill a thread during a crash?

Tags: python, python-3.x, multithreading, python-multithreading

Instances of a class `C` start a thread that runs a loop until a `run_worker` event gets cleared:

```py
import threading
class C:
    def __init__(self):
        self.run_worker = threading.Event()
        self.run_worker.set()
        self.worker = threading.Thread(target=self.fn_worker, args=())
        self.worker.start()

    def fn_worker(self): while self.run_worker.is_set(): pass # (or do stuff)

    def cleanup(self): self.run_worker.clear()
```

If `script.py` creates an instance `obj_c` and then crashes before `obj_c.cleanup()` is run, then the worker thread stays running forever.
The terminal hangs and I have to kill it.

Can I add something to `C` that guarantees its instances will cleanup if the instantiator or its parents crash?
If not, how can the code be restructured to avoid this problem?

Comment: In the post that was closed, someone suggested adding another exit condition to the worker, like a timer. I added this `Event` precisely to try and avoid such a timer.
Another solution is to wrap everything in the script with `try: (...) finally: obj_c.cleanup()`, but now `obj_c` isn't responsible for itself.

Comment: The standard mechanisms for ensuring code runs even if an exception occurs are `finally` blocks and context manager `__exit__` methods. Depending on how your `C` is used, it might be reasonable to add context manager support to `C`.